# ELF entry field and actual program entry

Tags: linux, elf

I use the readelf utility to check (-h) an executable file, and i see the e_entry field has the value: 0x8048530 . Then i recompile the checked program and have it to print its own program entry by adding the line: printf("%p\n", (void*)main) and outputs: 0x80485e4. Why do i have this difference? (OS: Linux 32-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point of an executable is usually not `main` itself but a platform specific function (that we'll call `_start`) which performs initialization before calling `main`.

Comment: Can i access the _start label from the main body?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question "*Can i access the _start label from the main body?*":

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void* res;
    #if defined(__i386__)
        asm("movl _start, %%eax" : "=a" (res));
    #elif defined(__x86_64__)
        asm("movq _start, %%rax" : "=a" (res));
    #else
        #error Unsupported architecture
    #endif
    printf("%p\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```